# Frictionless development of multiple SystemJS/JSPM packages

Tags: javascript, npm, system, jspm

I'm working on a set of JavaScript projects and some of these have dependencies between them. I've chosen JSPM as my package manager - which is all fine. But during development I want to have the most efficient frictionless way of working with this.

What is the best way for me to be able to have a dependency from one project to another in a totally transparent way - when I work on it locally, I get to just jump between projects without having to do any packaging or installation of packages and at the same time package information with its dependencies being what is expected to be for release (public package) and builds on the CI??

With NPM I could be doing `npm link`- anything similar I can be doing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`jspm link`](http://jspm.io/docs/linking.html)

Running `jspm link` in a module will publish it into the locally global "link" repository.

Running `jspm install --link` will then install a project from the "link" repository.

The only functional difference between `npm link` is that (for the moment at least) `jspm link` will need to be run every time your local code changes.  This can be automated with a watch task (see [jspm-cli#481](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/481)).

Comment: Excellent.. Thanks!   A watch task sounds like the way to go - love my feedback loops to be as tight as possible.

Comment: The beta version of 0.17 has a more optimized approach using symlinks directly, see [here](http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/linking.html). I might just try out that instead - thanks for leading me down the right path!